# Illustrator misshapes edges in exported *.svg

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, export

[image]Does anyone know why when I save out an SVG icon that my edges get misshapen and do not look like what I have designed; Example: Smooth edges are exported as sharp.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Bridget, thanks for your question and welcome to GD.SE! Could you lease show us a screenshot and tell us what export settings you used? That way, we can try and find a solution for you! If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Export settings: File > Export > SVG > Styling: Internal, Font: SVG, Images: Links, Object ID: Layer Names Decimal: 1, Minify and responsive.

Comment: I don't think the issue I am having is with the SVG settings though. I think it's with the vector shape. I checked all my settings/preferences and they look good.

Comment: can you attach a snapshot of your working file

Answer (score 1):

Outline your strokes, select them and then click `Object > Artboards > Fit to Selected Art`. Then try exporting again.

Comment: thanks for responding. i am not using strokes though. i was able to find a workaround but i still want to solve the issue. and the dartboard is larger than the vector image.